# pushState in React + Redux using connected-react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to push state to the browser and append to the pathname when a subreddit has changed.

In the example below the user chooses an option from `['reactjs', 'frontend']`. So when the user chooses `reactjs`, I want to changethe browser url to: `<url>/reddit/reactjs` or `<url>/reddit/frontend` based on the selection.

So when the user goes back and forward, I want to show data that was already fetched.

How can I make it work with react-redux for the example below? Normally, I was using `history.pushState(...)`.

Note: I am using `connected-react-router`

**index.js:**

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Root from './containers/Root'

render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**action.js:**

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch'

export const REQUEST_POSTS = 'REQUEST_POSTS'
export const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS'
export const SELECT_SUBREDDIT = 'SELECT_SUBREDDIT'
export const INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT = 'INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT'

export function selectSubreddit(subreddit) {
  return {
    type: SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
    subreddit
  }
}

export function invalidateSubreddit(subreddit) {
  return {
    type: INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
    subreddit
  }
}

function requestPosts(subreddit) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_POSTS,
    subreddit
  }
}

function receivePosts(subreddit, json) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
    subreddit,
    posts: json.data.children.map(child => child.data),
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}

function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
    return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
  }
}

function shouldFetchPosts(state, subreddit) {
  const posts = state.postsBySubreddit[subreddit]
  if (!posts) {
    return true
  } else if (posts.isFetching) {
    return false
  } else {
    return posts.didInvalidate
  }
}

export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(subreddit) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
      return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
    }
  }
}
```

**reducers.js:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
  INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
  REQUEST_POSTS,
  RECEIVE_POSTS
} from './actions'

function selectedSubreddit(state = 'reactjs', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_SUBREDDIT:
      return action.subreddit
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function posts(
  state = {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    items: []
  },
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        didInvalidate: true
      })
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      })
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  postsBySubreddit,
  selectedSubreddit
})

export default rootReducer
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'


// const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()


export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default function configureStore(preloadedState?: any) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer(history), // root reducer with router state
    preloadedState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        logger,
        routerMiddleware(history), // for dispatching history actions
        // ... other middlewares ...
      ),
    ),
  )

  return store
}
```

**Root.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from '../configureStore'
import AsyncApp from './AsyncApp'

const store = configureStore()

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AsyncApp />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**AsnycApp.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  selectSubreddit,
  fetchPostsIfNeeded,
  invalidateSubreddit
} from '../actions'
import Picker from '../components/Picker'
import Posts from '../components/Posts'

class AsyncApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleRefreshClick = this.handleRefreshClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.selectedSubreddit !== prevProps.selectedSubreddit) {
      const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
      dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
    }
  }

  handleChange(nextSubreddit) {
    this.props.dispatch(selectSubreddit(nextSubreddit))
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextSubreddit))
  }

  handleRefreshClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(invalidateSubreddit(selectedSubreddit))
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedSubreddit, posts, isFetching, lastUpdated } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Picker
          value={selectedSubreddit}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={['reactjs', 'frontend']}
        />
        <p>
          {lastUpdated && (
            <span>
              Last updated at {new Date(lastUpdated).toLocaleTimeString()}.{' '}
            </span>
          )}
          {!isFetching && (
            <button onClick={this.handleRefreshClick}>Refresh</button>
          )}
        </p>
        {isFetching && posts.length === 0 && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
        {!isFetching && posts.length === 0 && <h2>Empty.</h2>}
        {posts.length > 0 && (
          <div style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }}>
            <Posts posts={posts} />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AsyncApp.propTypes = {
  selectedSubreddit: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  lastUpdated: PropTypes.number,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { selectedSubreddit, postsBySubreddit } = state
  const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items: posts } = postsBySubreddit[
    selectedSubreddit
  ] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }

  return {
    selectedSubreddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AsyncApp)
```

**Picker.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Picker extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value, onChange, options } = this.props

    return (
      <span>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
        <select onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} value={value}>
          {options.map(option => (
            <option value={option} key={option}>
              {option}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </span>
    )
  }
}

Picker.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string.isRequired).isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

**Posts.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

Posts.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

---

**Update**:

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
...
handleChange(nextSubreddit) {
  this.props.dispatch(push('/reddit/' + nextSubreddit))
}
```

I placed this in the `handleChange()` method. When Picker changes, I push the state to the browser. However, when I go back and forward, the data does not change according to this url. I see the same data in every state.

Comment: You should connect your `Posts` component to redux and get the posts based on the option you have selected.

Comment: im a bit lost with this i think i've tried that too but didn't worked (probably i tested wrongly). Can you show me a piece of code? I will be very appreciate it :/

Comment: Also, AsnycApp.js is connected. Isn't this what you say? For example, if I manually click on a link i can navigate through browser but fetched (ajax) data does not get reflected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can handle this scenario using `history` property. We implement using listener of `history` and play with the `location` property which in turn provide `pathname`. It would be implement in `componentDidUpdate`. Everytime when back and forward button of browser clicked, the listener will called and service calls and state can be changed accordingly.

**AsyncApp.js**

```
// code here

import { history } from '../configureStore'
// code here

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.props.selectedSubreddit !== prevProps.selectedSubreddit) {
      const backBrowser = history.listen(location => {
           console.log(location.pathname)
           // code here
      }
      // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to push current path to browser, however It doesn't work with fetched data. I see same data when i go back or forward. Can you elaborate a little how to populate previous states data using above example? I've updated the question. I see samples on the net but none of them worked with Redux in above example.

Comment: so u need that when u use back and forward, data should change accordingly via service calls and state change parallely.

Comment: That is what I am asking for. I couldn't managed to make it work. Any help on above sample? If you illustrate a working sample I will understand better and find my mistake.

Comment: Ok. understood.. it would be great if u provide the demo of your code and i make changes in it and share u

Comment: If you are still interested. I made a working sample. Demo: https://react-7qfrxx.stackblitz.io/reactjs and its editable code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qfrxx    (Simply, switch between options then go back/forward. you will see url changes but content same)

Comment: Hi, I had update my answer. u can handle like that.

Comment: Hi, It didn't worked for me. I've updated my question. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Nope. It is working. I forgot to call `SelectDir` method

Comment: Thanks!! Have a great coding day today

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day and my other 2 days!